# Using strchr to overload >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, inputstream, strchr

I'm trying to overload the >> operator to read a single (created with `enum Symbol {e,a,b,c,d};`) Symbol:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & is, Symbol & sym) {
  Symbol Arr[]={e,a,b,c,d};
  char ch;
  is>>ch;
  if (strchr("eabcd",ch))
    sym=Arr[ch-'e'];
      else {
        is.unget(); 
        is.setstate(ios::failbit);
      }
  return is;
}
```

But this reads some trash (numbers) instead of what I was looking for, leading to a segmentation fault when trying to print it with my << overload, what am I doing wrong?
Edit: Oh, and of course I did add `using namespace std;` at the start, same with including `iostream` and `cstring`.

Comment: Just curious, what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: This is part of a larger project for my Object Programming course at a university, I need to read Symbols to then do operations on them with an addition table etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here. First, let's fix your bracing. Just always use braces. It's very difficult to see what's lined up with what:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & is, Symbol & sym) {
    Symbol Arr[]={e,a,b,c,d};
    char ch;
    is>>ch;
    if (strchr("eabcd",ch)) {
        sym=Arr[ch-'e'];
    }
    else {
        is.unget(); 
        is.setstate(ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Ok great. Now, what happens if the user inputs something like `'a'`. The `strchr` succeeds, and then you do `sym = Arr[ch - 'e']`. But `ch - 'e'` in this case is `-4`. That's some totally random bit of memory somewhere, so you're getting garbage. To actually use `strchr`, you'd need to do something like:

```
const char* options = "eabcd";
if (const char* p = strchr(options, ch)) {
    sym = Arr[p - options];
}
```

But that's kind of awful. I'd suggest just using a switch:

```
switch (ch) {
    case 'e': sym = e; break;
    case 'a': sym = a; break;
    ...
    default:
        is.unget();
        is.setstate(ios::failbit);
}
```

**Also**, `is >> ch` could fail and you're not checking that. You should:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Symbol& sym) {
    char ch;
    if (is >> ch) {
        switch(ch) { ... }
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: But why is it `-4` and not 1? `a` comes after `e` in my code, am I misunderstanding how `strchr` works?

Comment: @GizmoofArabia You're subtracting `char`s. Your enum is irrelevant.

Comment: @GIzmoofArabia, No. When you're doing substruction, 'a' - 'e' is negative, because you're performing ASCII code substruction. Have a look at [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/). Look at dec and char columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I stuck with `strchr` because I'm not sure if the person checking my work later would be ok with `switch`, `strchr` was kind of suggested for this. So why did you say your 1st solution was "awful", could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @GizmoofArabia Because you're just checking if the inputted char was one of 5 possible values, a `switch` is the more direct way of doing something like that. `strchr` takes a lot longer to reason about here... it's kinda confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If `ch` is `'a'`, `ch - 'e'` (97 - 101) will be a negative number (-4), which will lead to accessing the array `Arr` out of bounds. That leads to undefined behavior.

The way you have your symbols, you'll need to use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (ch)
{
   case 'a':
      sym = a;
      break;

   case 'b':
      sym = b;
      break;

   case 'c':
      sym = c;
      break;

   case 'd':
      sym = d;
      break;

   case 'e':
      sym = e;
      break;

   default:
     // Nothing to do
     break;
}
```

If you want to use `Arr`, you will need to define `Arr` as:

```
 Symbol Arr[]={a,b,c,d,e};
```

Then, you can access the array as below and avoid the `switch` statement:

```
sym=Arr[ch-'a'];  // ch - 'a' is 0 when ch is 'a'
                  // ch - 'a' is 4 when ch is 'e'.
```

Comment: `'e' - ch` will not work because the elements of `Arr` are not in sequential order from `e` down to `a`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for pointing out the error. It's fixed now.